# Getting error while running SoapUI project through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception, soapui, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm getting below error while running SoapUI project through Eclipse.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load i4jinst from C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.6.0\lib\i4jinst.dll, false, D:\Soap UI E2E Framework\SoapUI E2E Framework\platform.zip, false, D:\Soap UI E2E Framework\SoapUI E2E Framework\i4jinst.dll
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.Common.init(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.ACLHandling.(Unknown Source)**

Can anyone help me out this this error?

Comment: **How** are you "running SoapUI project through Eclipse"? You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you share the use case. ideally people dont use eclipse/intellij for soapui tool. Is soapui not able to solve your case ?